# Get Type of Object from String Value

Tags: c#

I am writing a customer class which will read CS files and spit out information based on method names and their various parameters.

This essentially reads each line looking for keys (public, class, etc) and then sees what its all about.  Anyway this bit works fine, what I'm having issues with is dealing with various different Types.

So what I need to do is work out whether the type is one found natively in .Net, or something I've created, I'm really not bothered which way round just as long as I have some way of telling.

I've tried `Type t = Type.GetType("My.Namespace.Classname");` but this just returns null even with the full namespace and name of my custom class object.  However if I was to do the same code but with System.String it works perfectly fine, but I can't really account for each possible namespace in the entire framework.   This will mean I need a way to get the type without the full namespace, or know how to check my own custom objects using GetType.

Can anybody provide any suggestions on how to go about this?  Even if it was creating a new instance of the objects that would be enough, but again I don't have the full namespace for .Net objects.

Edit: Bit of a  background
What I'm doing is reading classes that I've created in a StreamReader, reason being that I'm creating lots of them and need to do making between objects that one system will be able to understand, and another, so this code would read everything and just create the mapping for me.  And in most cases this is perfectly fine, it is only when I have custom types, so I want to identify these are mark them.

Comment: Use `Roslyn` to parse C# source code.

Comment: So in other words, you're parsing code files and trying to determine if a type used in the code is a .NET or 3rd party type?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can't just get a type of a text file; your running code has to have reference to the assembly where the class resides.
There ways to compile and use code on the fly. If it would be useful to you, let us know. Note that if you're willing to compile the text file so you'll be able to ready details from this class using the .Net Framework itself in a typed way instead of interpreting code as text.

Comment: @DStanley kinda yeah.  I've updated the original post with a bit more info at the bottom.

Comment: If you could look each class (no automated process) would you be able to say if it's a "custom" type? How would you realize the difference? Just using your feeling by reading the namespace, for example? I mean, before trying to automate the process, you have to identify a consistent way to differentiate the supplier of the class. Have you already found this way?

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried Type t = Type.GetType("My.Namespace.Classname"); but this
>   just returns null

You need to provide the full assembly-qualified name:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("My.Namespace.Classname, MyAssembly");
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Parameters
>
> typeName
>   Type: System.String
>
> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing
>   assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name
>   qualified by its namespace.

Anyway, if you're looking to parse C# code an analyze it, I would take a look at [*NRefactory* - an open source C# parser -](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory).

[Here's an introduction in CodeProject to NRefactory](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408663/Using-NRefactory-for-analyzing-Csharp-code).

Comment: This won't work if the referenced assembly used by the target project is not currenly loaded.

Comment: @BasBrekelmans MSDN says: **You can use the GetType method to obtain a Type object for a type in another assembly, if the you know its namespace-qualified name. GetType causes loading of the assembly specified in typeName.**

Comment: The OP never talked about read another assembly. He's trying to read CS files.

Comment: @Caffé It's implicitly in the question. See `Type t = Type.GetType("My.Namespace.Classname")`, and the fact that returns null.

Comment: @Caffé I guess you're who downvoted the question. While SO lets anyone up/downvote questions or answers, I would say that before downvoting, reader should read questions and answers carefully...

Comment: I've read carefully and have found the following: "I am writing a customer class which will read CS files". He doesn't have an assembly, he has just tried to get the type based on its namespace name.

Comment: @Caffé And again, this is the mistake: `Type.GetType` requires the full assembly qualified name, and this is why OP is getting a `null` value. Check Jon Skeet's answer, which goes in the same direction as mine. And I've provided a suggestion, NRefactory, so OP can start exploring other approach to solve his/her problem.

Comment: @Caffé If it's not about reading Q&A carefully, maybe it's about OP has an issue and an answerer gives an answer to why the issue is happening. And StackOverflow isn't a free code provider... It's about giving some kind of guidance......

Comment: Actually, `Type.GetType` doesn't require a full assembly qualified name in some situations, and for all situations, you **have to have an assembly**. That's why your answer doesn't work for OP, who was clear in his point of reading "CS files". I've tried to undo my donwvote after your update but SO prevent me to do this.

Comment: @Caffé I know about these cases where you don't need to provide fully-qualified names, but since there's no actual sample code to see how's OP's approach, I tried to fix a concrete issue: a custom type in a satellite assembly, case where you need to provide the full assembly qualified name. Also, we don't know if analyzed files are part of a project and these assemblies are also there...

Comment: @Caffé If not, the approach is an epic fail! ;) And OP should go with the *NRefactory* approach...

Comment: @Caffé About the downvote, don't worry... At the end of the day, I'm not a reputation wh*re... I'm a knowledge wh*re!

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried `Type t = Type.GetType("My.Namespace.Classname");` but this just returns null even with the full namespace and name of my custom class object.

I suspect that's because it's not in the calling assembly or mscorlib, which are the only two assemblies checked by `Type.GetType` for names which aren't assembly-qualified.

If you know all the assemblies involved, you could run through each of them calling `Assembly.GetType(namespaceQualifiedName)` on each of them.

However, if you don't even have the namespace-qualified name, you should possibly create a lookup of *all* types in *all* the relevant assemblies, based on their names. For example:

```
var lookup = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                       .ToLookup(t => t.Name);
```

At that point, for each name you have(e.g. `Classname` in your example) you can find all the types with that name:

```
foreach (var type in lookup[name])
{
    // Do something with type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Type.GetType(some_type_name)` will return type object if `some_type_name` is name of type declared any assemblies **loaded** at the moment, or in `Mscorlib.dll`

So if your are parsing your types from .cs files and not loading assebly - it will always be null with types names from your source file